# How to make links work, regardless of location in directory structure?

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, href

So in the included image, you can see a copy of the website I'm currently working on. The site is going to have separate pages for each of the company's machines. Obviously the navigation bar and menu bar are going to be the same throughout the whole website so I thought I'd make use of a single line of PHP script to just load the menu in each time.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjATR.png
(Attached image as I do not have +10 rep yet)

Though, from what I understand, the pages within folders (Not within root) wont be able to link to the rest of the site without the use of `../` within the `href`.

So if I load the menu part of the site containing the navbar, etc, it won't work on all the pages because they'll all be within different folders, meaning every folder will need it's own version of the navbar PHP import.

Am I going about this the wrong way? I'm just trying to minimize the amount of code I'm using on each page. Not only that, but once I finish the site if I have to make a change to the menu-bar, I don't want to have to update 30-40+ pages. I figured the PHP import would save me that sort of trouble? Is there a better way of doing this that isn't terribly complicated?

It should also be noted that I'm doing this in HTML5 with Twitter-Bootstrap as my main CSS.

I would also be making a similar PHP call that would import a footer as well.
If I missed anything that could be of help, please do ask.

**TL;DR** - How do I make links work throughout the entirety of the site, regardless of where they are in the folder hierarchy. Thought about using a tiny PHP script that would contain the menubar, etc and would be loaded on every single page. Though I'm not sure if that will work due to folders?

Comment: You can always set absolute links, so instead of `../image.jpg` you could do `http://www.yoursite.com/directory/image.jpg`

Comment: See, I suppose something like that would be good to do once the site it actually live but unfortunately on my local machine, the URL wouldn't work. Is there no method that works in all cases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to start your links from `/`. This means that url is started from site root.
For example:

```
<a href="/products/kettles/kettles_patch.html">Patch Kettles</a>
```

Comment: I think I had tried that from earlier on in development but my images and other links that were already in folders wouldn't work. A page that was located in `/products/kettles` wouldn't be able to load an image from `/images/products/kettles` unless I did `../../` first.

Comment: Do you test this, when running from server or just open index.html file with the browser (e.g. path in address bar begins from file://...)? In the second case this solution will not work. But when you open site served from served it will.

Comment: I am currently unable to upload the website I am working until it is fully completed. So, like you said, this solution wouldn't work for the whole development stage :( . I need to be able to link images and other pages to see what they look like.

Comment: I understood. I very recommend you to setup some server on your local machine for development. There is not solution, which will work without server. [EasyPHP](http://www.easyphp.org/introduction.php) for  example. If any help needed, you are welcome.

Comment: Wouldn't something like [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) work better?

Comment: Yeah, you may use XAMPP if you prefer.

Comment: I'll give that a try tomorrow then I suppose. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Just define a constant with the root path and `echo` it within all the links inside the pages that are contained in a folder like this:

[Put this in a file that you include through out your whole website (e.g. like the file with your database connection if you have one)]

```
define('BASE_URL' , 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/');
```

Than just add an `echo` in the start of each link:

```
<a href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>index.html">Home</a>
```

And for images the same thing:

```
<img src="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>images/img_01.jpg"/>
```

Comment: This method seems a bit more complicated than the rest, though I think it's the one that would work the most efficiently in my current state of development. From what it seems, this would definitely work while the website is live but will it work while I'm developing on my local machine?

Comment: I've been developing websites quite a while now and this is the method that worked best for me in all the cases, speacially when you are doing `routing`

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `/path/to/image.jpg` to get absolute paths, while still being fine if your domain name ever changes.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you're asking unfortunately. I assume that once `menu.html` was imported, it would be relevant to the location of the current page. So if I had something in `/product/kettles`, it's menu bar links would have to use two `../../` rather than a document that was only in `/product`. No?

Comment: Yeah I misread the question initially, apologies! Updated my answer.

Comment: Ah, I see, thank you! And this will work, regardless of where the current page is within the website folder hierarchy?

Comment: That will be relative to the site root, so relative to, for example: `http://www.example.com/`

Comment: This solution has not worked. When I click on a link to attempt to go back to the home page, nothing happens. I changed the `<li><a href="../../index.html">Home</a></li>` to `<li><a href="/index.html">Home</a></li>` but to no avail.

Comment: Nothing at all happens?

Comment: No sir, the page just sits there. I think that it is looking for the file within the root of that current directory rather than the root directory of the entire website?

Comment: You'll need to run it using a local webserver, rather than opening the file itself in a browser.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid that path but I suppose I'll have to go download XAMPP then. Thank you though!